# In Python script, how to make streamlink to write to a log file.>

Tags: python, streamlink

Hi I have a python script that looks for a video stream, if the stream is found it will do something.

When streamlink does NOT find a stream it displays a message (this is standard functionality) "Could not get video info - ERROR: Video unavailable".

In the documentation it says you can write to a log file but I am at a loss... this is what I call

```
 streams = streamlink.streams (channel_stream)
```

How do I complete that statement to have streamlink to log to /var/stramlink.log

Thanks in advance.
h

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://streamlink.github.io/api.html) it looks like you can set log file settings on a streamlink session using an instance of the session:

```
subprocess-errorlog (bool) Log errors from subprocesses to a file located in the temp directory

subprocess-errorlog-path (str) Log errors from subprocesses to a specific file

ffmpeg-verbose (bool) Log stderr from ffmpeg to the console

ffmpeg-verbose-path (str) Specify the location of the ffmpeg stderr log file
```

These settings can be set something like:

```
streamlink.set_option('subprocess-errorlog', true)
streamlink.set_option('subprocess-errorlog-path', '/path/to/streamlink_error.log')
streamlink.set_option('ffmpeg-verbose', true)
streamlink.set_option('ffmpeg-verbose-path', '/path/to/ffmpeg_error.log')
```

Comment: Hi j_b, thanks so much for your answer.

I have 
''' streams = streamlink.streams (channel_stream)
    class streamlink.set_option('subprocess-errorlog-path', 'streamlink_error.log')'''

But that gives me an error 
'''"AttributeError: module 'streamlink' has no attribute 'set_option'"'''

Not sure how to actually implement it... been going around in circles :-) and can't seem to break out of it... LOL. 

H

Comment: How did you get the instance of `streamlink` that you are using?  The documentation indicates that it should be an instance of a Session class:  `class streamlink.Streamlink(options=None)
A Streamlink session is used to keep track of plugins, options and log settings.`

Comment: In the python script I call.  Import streamlink       and then I do  streams = streamlink.streams (channel_stream)